# Cannot find the definition of a constant

Tags: c++, cmake, tritonserver

I am trying to add a new accelerator to the Nvidia Triton inference server.

One of the last thing I need to do it add a new constant like this one (`kOpenVINOExecutionAccelerator`) but for some reason I cannot find where it is defined:

https://github.com/triton-inference-server/onnxruntime_backend/search?q=kOpenVINOExecutionAccelerator

I'm quite new to cmake, is this some kind of cmake trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the Triton Inference Server Backend [here](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/backend/blob/40881004655dd8a3b253fb5e98102ce7eea1874c/include/triton/backend/backend_common.h#L280).